# How to prevent leak from my provider access_key while using Terraform

Tags: azure, security, terraform

I did not found any great documentation on the way to avoid setting the backend configuration or the access_key of Terraform out of the source code.

Is this the best way ? : [Hashicorp Terraform Remote State and Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55031661/hashicorp-terraform-remote-state-and-azure)

Any one have a great solution for it ?

```
backend "azurerm" {
  resource_group_name  = "tfstate"
  storage_account_name = "<storage_account_name>"
  container_name       = "tfstate"
  key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
  access_key           = "value" # This is a bad value to expose
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage [TF_VAR_name](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/environment-variables#tf_var_name)

> Environment variables can be used to set variables. The environment variables must be in the format TF_VAR_name and this will be checked last for a value.

So you need to create `variable "access_key"` and then set environment variable TF_VAR_access_key and assign your access key.

Your terraform code will be

```
backend "azurerm" {
  resource_group_name  = "tfstate"
  storage_account_name = "<storage_account_name>"
  container_name       = "tfstate"
  key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
  access_key           = var.access_key
}
```

and your pipeline

```
- bash: |
     # run terraform here
  env:
    TF_VAR_access_key: $(access_key)
```

`access_key` should be stored as secret in variable group, or loaded from key vault.